# what does service layer stand for in MVC design pattern

Tags: java, web-application-design

I noticed a lot of java web applications added a service layer between the controller layer and the DAO layer. It will deal with the business logic, get the response from the DAO layer and return the result to the controller layer. I am confused what does it stand for in MVC and why? Thanks.

Comment: (Assuming individuals are not already in the process of writing a post) I think the down votes should be explained. Unless I'm missing something, this seems like a legitimate question to me. I suppose it might be considered "general", but I don't think its "unclear" to anyone familiar with Java web frameworks such as Spring (for example).

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/175952

Answer (score 0):

service layer ( as well as DAO ) is not a part of MVC. It provides the Model which is Controller is able to represent as view

Answer (score 0):

The Service layer actually does not stand for MVC but it helps in making your code modular and  open for extensions like Open-Close design patterns.

DAO Layer should be used only for managing connections and performing the CRUD operations. It is the Service Layer which actually provides the logic to your result set fetched from DAO layer.

I can say that the Service Layer provides a layer of Abstraction to the incoming request.